# Who was the "Starship Troopers" representative who appeared in "The Cat Who Walks Through Walls"?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, starship-troopers

From *"The Cat Who Walks Through Walls"* [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_Who_Walks_Through_Walls) article:

> During a meeting of the Council of the Time Scouts, representatives from every major time line and setting written by Heinlein appear, including Glory Road and Starship Troopers; and a reference is made to other authors' works as well.

**Who was the representative from *Starship Troopers*?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The members of the Circle of the Ouroboros are introduced as:

- Master Mobyas Toras of Barsoom (Timeline 1, Coded John Carter)
- Her Wisdom Star, Arbitrar of the Ninety Universes (Composite timeline, Coded Cyrano)
- Woodrow Wilson Smith, Senior of the Howard Families (Timeline 2, Coded Leslie LeCroix)
- Dr. Jubal Harshaw (Timeline 3, Coded Neil Armstrong)
- Dr. Hilda Mae Burroughs (Timeline 4, Coded Ballox O'Malley)
- Commander Ted Smith (Timeline 5, Coded DuQuesne)
- Captain John Sterling (Timeline 6, Coded Neil Armstrong Alternate)
- Sky Marshal Samuel Beaux (Timeline 7, Coded Fairacre)

In *Starship Troopers*, the person with the rank of Sky Marshal commands Earth's entire military, so we can reasonably assume that the representative from *Starship Troopers* is Sky Marshal Samuel Beaux.

Comment: If anyone is wondering. Ted Smith is a Lensman - E. E. Smith, and the one from _Glory Road_ is Her Wisdom Star.

Comment: ...and Marc DuQuesne is the antagonist of Richard Seaton in _The Skylark of Space_ (by E. E. Smith).